# Typemock not integrating with VS2017 and NUnit3

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit-3.0, typemock, typemock-isolator

Trying to debug tests that use TypeMock and I get the following error:

```
TypeMock.TypeMockException: '
*** Typemock Isolator is currently disabled. Enable using the following:

 * Within Visual Studio: 
   - Use Typemock Smart Runner  
   - For other runners, Choose Typemock Menu and click "Integrate with Other Runners"

 * To run Typemock Isolator as part of an automated process you can:
    - run tests via TMockRunner.exe command line tool
    - use 'TypeMockStart' tasks for MSBuild or NAnt

For more information consult the documentation (see 'Running Unit Tests in an Automated Build')'
```

"Integrate with other Runners" is selected.

Versions:

- Visual Studio: 15.9.4
- TypeMock: 8.6.5.1
- NUnit: 3.7.1

Installing the latest versions of TypeMock and NUnit does not fix the issue.

Edit: it works fine when I 'run' the tests. It only fails in 'debug'.

Comment: From Coral: • What runner are you using to run your tests? • Do you use other tools as well (e.g dotCover, Coverage)? It would be helpful if you could send us the logs directly to the following e-mail address: support@typemock.com

You can retrieve the logs via (Typemock->Options->Logs-> Mocking ( check SmartRunner as well if you are running via SmartRunner)

Comment: I am using the default Microsoft test runner. I'm not running any other tools. I tried your possible solution, but that did not work.

Comment: Hi @DavidPoxon, I had the same problem with Typemock 8.6.2.
I contacted Typemock support and they instructed me to upgrade Nunit test adapter and Nunit to the latest stable version, that solved my issue. You should give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem (as provided by Typemock Support) was as follows.

Create a file named `knownRunners.dat` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Typemock\Isolator\8.6` (Typemock remarked that this might *not* be the location of my Typemock 8.6 installation - so it would be best to confirm.) The contents of the file should be:

```
testhost.x86.exe
testhost.exe
```

After doing this I restarted Visual Studio, and I could debug tests without any issues.

**EDIT (2021-03-08)**

In at least Typemock 8.2.3 this issue became intermittent. Updating the contents of `knownRunners.dat` to the following should resolve any issues:

```
testhost.net48.x86.exe
```

I found version 8.9.3.1 to work without any issues.

Answer (score -2):

My name is Coral, and I work for Typemock.

I noticed by chance your post here and I'd like to help you :)

Do you mind answering the following questions, please:

•    What runner are you using to run your tests?
•    Do you use other tools as well (e.g  dotCover, Coverage)?

Additionally, I'd appreciate it if you could run following task for me:

Go to Typemock->Options->Mocking Integration and check that "Enable Mocking integration" and
"Enable Auto Linking(with other Coverage Tools)" boxes are checked too.
Then, Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2017 as an admin
- Run the command: devenv /Setup
- Wait until it finishes
- Open your solution

Try to debug your tests now and please let me know if this solves the issue.

It would be helpful if you could send us the logs directly to the following e-mail address: support@typemock.com

You can retrieve the logs via (Typemock->Options->Logs-> Mocking ( check SmartRunner as well if you are running via SmartRunner)

I hope this helps. In the future, feel free to open a ticket at Typemock support:
https://typemock.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new

Comment: Hey Coral, this doesn't answer the question and contains a lot of support details. It would be better suited as a comment below the question to help with troubleshooting. Then when the trouble has been shot, add a solution here for this particular problem.

Comment: Hi Coral, I have responded to your questions as a comment to my original post. Thank you!

Comment: Hey David, please send us the logs to Support@typemock.com

Comment: In addition, please mention if you are debugging via SmartRunner or via MS test runner. Thanks! @DavidPoxon

Comment: @CoralTypemock MS test runner.

Comment: @DavidPoxon We need the logs. Can you please send it to support@typemock.com? Cheers